# How to convert tweepy api calls to async

Tags: python, asynchronous

I have a list of **98000+** twitter handles. With tweepy I want to fetch some informations like username, description etc for a specific user.
For this amount of data, The method I am following is really slow. So I want to implement asyncio.

I am currently loop through the list of tweeter handles and fetch data for every single handle.

My code is given below

```
# import tweeter API credentials
import credentials as c

# import tweeter user handles fetched from DB
import get_handles

# import required modules
import json
import tweepy

# List of tweeter handles
handles = get_handles.twitter_handles

# authentication
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(c.API_KEY, c.API_SECRET_KEY)
auth.set_access_token(c.ACCESS_TOKEN, c.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth, timeout=5)

# open a file inorder to write data fetched from API
with open('userinfo2.json', 'w') as outfile:

    for x in range(9508, len(handles)):
        user = api.get_user(handles[x])
        data = {
            'name': user.name, 'description': user.description,
            'profile_image_url': user.profile_image_url, 
            'followers_count': user.followers_count,
        }
        json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)
        print('%s number of data fetched', (x))

outfile.close()
```

How can I convert this code in asynchronous?

Comment: You can chunk your `userinfo2.json` and create a function to send the request using `tweepy` as you wrote, then establish several threads which call the mentioned function concurrently/async

Comment: However, there is a limitation: [max per 15 minutes is 18,000](https://github.com/ropensci/rtweet/issues/254).

Comment: tweepy. AsyncStream is WIP in this PR. 
 https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/1491

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a wrapper over tweepy.API to achieve this

```
# atweepy.py

import asyncio
import functools

import tweepy  # type: ignore
from tweepy import *


async def acall(f, *args, **kwargs):
    return await asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(
        None, lambda: f(*args, **kwargs)
    )


def awrap(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return await acall(f, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


def create_aproxy_class(cls):
    class AsyncProxy:
        __name__ = cls.__name__
        __doc__ = cls.__doc__

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.proxy = cls(*args, **kwargs)

        def __getattr__(self, attr):
            attr = getattr(self.proxy, attr)
            return awrap(attr) if callable(attr) else attr

    return AsyncProxy


API = create_aproxy_class(tweepy.API)
```

And to create the API

```
import atweepy

async def create_twitter(key, secret, access_token, access_token_secret):
    try:
        auth = atweepy.OAuthHandler(key, secret)
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        return
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = atweepy.API(
        auth,
        retry_count=3,
        retry_delay=10,
        wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True,
        wait_on_rate_limit=True,
        compression=True,
    )
    return api
```

Then to call any API method you *must* place an `await` before it.

```
api = create_api(key, secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
me = await api.me()
tweet = await api.get_status(some_id)
tl = await api.mentions_timeline()
```

This will wrap all methods of API with an `.run_in_executor` call. This is not ideal but it's working for me. Please take a look at https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/732 for more information on this subject.

Best regards